How to stop User from creating too many instances at Sign-up?
I'm creating a CV website, where the user on sign up is prompted to provide his qualifications. If his qualification/skill doesn't exist in the database he is allowed to add it. But it occurs to me that a sufficiently bored and/or annoying person might choose to add a bunch of nonsensical skills and clutter. Is there a way to limit this?
I was thinking maybe a soft limit per IP address, you can't add more than X numbers from said address. But that poses problems for shared addresses, like an office or a university.
A second option is to make added skills appear to other uses only if enough people have added them, but I'm not sure how I would even start implementing this.

It would seem that a user working on a CV needs an account, and you would impose limits per account vs going to IP wide bans - or am I missing something?

That would be sensible, but I am following the clients specification that you can add skills and talents, etc, on the sign up page itself.
It's on the figma and everything :'(

Is there a guest state where you don't need an account to submit your CV? Something that really bothers me as a user when I'm filling all those forms is that the site is not suggesting tags for the skills set. Is like when you're asking a new question in stackExchange that you need certain level of expertise to create new labels.

A sign-up page shouldn't be too information-rich, you run the risk of users abandoning ("This is too much work") before giving account/contact info to get back into the workflow later. Part of our job as UXers is to help steer clients into making better UX decisions, not just taking orders from them.

@Melek what does being 'on the figma' mean? That it has been tested and validated so therefore it makes sense to design a solution for the feature?

@EmmanuelCuevas There isn't one no. That'd be cool to implement though.

@Izquierdo You're right I suppose, I was hoping to save myself the trouble of a meeting xD, but I'll raise it with them and decide from there.

@MichaelLai No, it meens the client has paid someone to design a website "frontend"  in figma, which isn't a tool I'm familiar with but it's just drawings as far as I know. The client then handed me a link to these figma schemas/drawings and told me to create the website.

@Melek is this really how things work in the design and implement hand-off these days? Maybe if there's an interactive prototype version in Figma, but that is still far from a comprehensive documentation of the requirements.

There are many potential solutions to this problem, and one of them could be simply to try and match a user input to the closest category, and if there are no clear matches or if a user indicates that they want to use their own input, then you allow it. But because the effort is much greater, it will hopefully discourage users from entering their own values.
Alternatively, you can allow users to submit their own values for approval, which gets them past this step while allowing you to review or control what actually gets entered. There are many different potential solutions, so you'll have to choose one based on implementation constraints (or figma concepts?).

I think I might go with a mix and match, halve the sign up page and have the add skills portion only appear after the email has been verified, and also implement that first option while I'm at it.
